# Adding super user with admin role in .net core framework

Tags: asp.net-core

currently I'm trying to add a super User with Admin role in ASP.Net Core web app.
I want to add this user at startup, I spend some time researching about the subject without any success.
The sartup looks very standard and out of the box as follows

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets();

            // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: The Startup class is a bad place to do that because you need the user to login first. The best way to handle this is on the Login action in the AccountController.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I need this at startup as this user supposed to be a super user and known by admins, it shall be in the database already and if not exists to be added there. So when you login you use this user. Can you give an example how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter `ApplicationDbContext dbContext` into `Configure` method - dependency injection will create appropriate object and you can Find/Add required users:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    ...

    if (dbContext.Users.Find(x => Name == "superadmin") == null)
    {
        db.Users.Add(new User { Name = "superadmin", ... });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Or you may add `UserManager` into parameters and use it for users manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I need to add a user with admin privileges that will be known for administrators and it shall be hard coded; Your code does add only a user..

Comment: I give you a way to add data to database during app startup. You can add any data, including roles, claims etc. - depending on your needs.

Comment: Indeed and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the hint.